# What is the bandwidth of a Standard B1ms Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I cannot find any documentation on what is the bandwidth of a Standard B1ms machine.. if you have any info, please share.

Comment: Can you post this question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general

I am also having trouble finding this information and I believe it is due to the nature of the B series. however, we should make sure to include this in the documentation and this path is a good way to achieve that :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `iperf3` to test the bandwidth in your Azure VM.

More information about use `iperf3` to test bandwidth, please refer to this [blog](https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/).